# pushing same project to two different Git repositories

Tags: eclipse, git

My project is required to be placed at two different git repositories as per client's requirement. Is there any way using which I can do this through eclipse or command line?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+to+two+remote+repositories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add anothr remote to your actual one. So you would have an "origin" which is conventionally the name you use and an originClient

```
git remote add originClient git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

`git push -u originClient yourBranchName`

Comment: Thanks @Giova.panasiti for replying. I'm not sure if I understood you completely. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I'll try to make myself more clear.

You can have multiple url (github, gitlab etc) on the same repository. When you add a url you usually add it as 'remote' in git. (Ex: git remote add origin) and we all call it origin as a standard but you can have multiple URLs on the same git project and just pushing the commits to the remote you prefer.